# Rename single file using rename command ignoring the file's extension

Tags: linux, rename

This will rename all files with jpg extension.

```
rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *.jpg
```

This will rename the file but will Rename the extension too.

```
rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' image.jpg
```

How to rename a single file without touching the extension?

```
example.jpg
```

Putout should be:

```
EXAMPLE.jpg
```

Comment: Does the first command _not_ up-case the filename suffix? It does when I try it.

Comment: @Kusalananda the Q seems to be asking how to avoid changing the suffix, as given by the sample input/output pair

Comment: yes you are right my goal is to rename one file without renaming the suffix

Answer (score 2):

with **rename**

```bsh
rename  -n 's/.*\./\U$&/'
```

- `-n` argument is for not making changes and show you what's going to happen.
- `.*` argument in regex world is select **everything**, used together with `\.` is to select everything before the dot[.] ⇾ `.*\.` select everything before the dot.

  - Escape characters with `\`[backslash] because `.`[dot] has special meaning in **regex**.
- `\U` argument means uppercase until, this is an **Escape sequence** in Perl regular expressions, it has to be used with `\`[backslash]
- `$&` argument is used to find the string matched in the last successful pattern search. example `/find/$&ADD/` returns: findADD

###### returns:

```bsh
rename(fellowSHIP.jpg, FELLOWSHIP.jpg)
rename(retorno2.jpg, RETORNO2.jpg)
rename(retorno3.jpg, RETORNO3.jpg)
rename(retorno4.jpg, RETORNO4.jpg)
rename(shein1.jpg, SHEIN1.jpg)
rename(shein2.jpg, SHEIN2.jpg)
rename(shein3.jpg, SHEIN3.jpg)
rename(shein4.jpg, SHEIN4.jpg)
rename(shein-girl1.jpg, SHEIN-GIRL1.jpg)
rename(sheingirl2.jpg, SHEINGIRL2.jpg)
rename(twoTowers1.jpg, TWOTOWERS1.jpg)
rename(twoTowers2.jpg, TWOTOWERS2.jpg)
rename(twoTowers3.jpg, TWOTOWERS3.jpg)
rename(twoTowers4.jpg, TWOTOWERS4.jpg)
rename(twoTowers5.jpg, TWOTOWERS5.jpg)
rename(twoTowers6.jpg, TWOTOWERS6.jpg)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rename 's/(.*)(\.[^.]+)/\U$1\E$2/' example.jpg
```

- `s/` start substitution
- `(.*)` match the filename part (any character, any amount) before the suffix, captured in first group
- `(\.[^.]+)` match suffix, a `.` followed by one or more non-`.` characters, captured in second group
- `/` start replacement
- `\U` uppercase (until `\E`)
- `$1` insert first matched group
- `\E` end case modification
- `$2` insert second matched group
- `/` end substitution

Comment: @rowboat That's much better! You should write an answer and I'll delete mine!

Answer (score 1):

Note that (beside the unrelated and very limited one in `util-linux`) there are now a few variants of the perl `rename` command (originally [a very short example script that came with `perl` 3.0](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/a687059cbaf2c6fdccb5e0fae2aee80ec15625a8/eg/rename)).

With the one from https://metacpan.org/dist/File-Rename and found in the `rename` package on recent Debian-based systems, to turn to uppercase all ASCII letters in the name of an arbitrary file, but not in the extension if any, you'd do:

```
rename -d -- 's/.*\.|.*/\U$&/s' "$file"
```

Where:

- `-d` makes sure the dirname of the file is not affected.
- `--` is needed with that implementation as otherwise a `$file` starting with `-` would be taken as an option (with disastrous consequences for a file called `--e=exec("rm -rf ~")` for instance).
- the `s` flag to the `s`ubstitute is needed as otherwise `.` would not match on a newline character (a character that is as valid as any in a file name).
- `.*\.|.*` matches either anything up to the rightmost `.` (as `.*` is greedy) or everything, bearing in mind that `perl` tries the left pattern first and contrary to POSIX regexps, doesn't try to see if the other one may yield a longer match. So it would match up to before the extension for files with an extension, and the whole filename for those without.
- `$&` is what was matched. Prefixed with `\U`, that's converted to uppercase like in `ex`/`vi` where `perl` borrowed it from.

Examples with `-n` (for dry-run):

```
$ rename -n -d -- 's/.*\.|.*/\U$&/s' $'--e=system("echo reboot") #/foo\nbar.jpg'
rename(--e=system("echo reboot") #/foo
bar.jpg, --e=system("echo reboot") #/FOO
BAR.jpg)
$ rename -n -d -- 's/.*\.|.*/\U$&/s' .config/gtkrc
rename(.config/gtkrc, .config/GTKRC)
$ rename -n -d -- 's/.*\.|.*/\U$&/s' .bashrc
$
```

(in `.bashrc` here, `bashrc` is considered as an extension).

Now, one problem is that it only works on ASCII file names.

It would convert a UTF-8 `Stéphane.jpg` to `STéPHANE.jpg` instead of `STÉPHANE.jpg` for instance (at least where that `é` is in precomposed form) or worse convert a BIG5-HKSCS `Stéphane.jpg` to `St<U+F310>phane.jpg`.

Working around that with `rename` is a bit of a pain. You need something like:

```
rename -n  -d -- '
  use Encode::Locale;
  use Encode;

  $_ = decode(locale_fs => $_);
  s/.*\.|.*/\U$&/s;
  $_ = encode(locale_fs => $_)' "$file"
```

To consider the files as being encoded in the locale's charset.

Beware however that it would turn bytes that can't be decoded into a character into some replacement character (something like `?` or `�` depending on the locale; in the C locale, that includes all byte values above 127).

In the end, it may be easier and safer to do it with your shell's operators. Like in `zsh`:

```
case $file:t in
  (*.*) newfile=$file:h/$file:t:r:u.$file:e;;
  (*) newfile=$file:h/$file:t:u;;
esac
[[ $file = $newfile ]] || mv -i -- $file $newfile
```

(where `:t`, `:h`, `:r`, `:e`, `:u` are csh-style modifiers that yield respectively the `t`ail, `h`ead, `r`ootname, `e`xtension, and turn to `u`ppercase).

`zsh`'s operators will do their best effort: convert characters that can be decoded and leave alone the sequences of bytes that can't be decoded.

`zsh` also has its own builtin batch renaming tool: `zmv`, implemented as an autoloadable function:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '(*).(*)' '$1:u.$2'
```

(to rename only the non-hidden files that do have an extension)

`zmv` also does a few sanity checks before starting the renaming which also makes it safer than `rename`.